# SQLITE_ERROR: Connection is closed when connecting from Spark via JDBC to SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache Spark 1.5.1 and trying to connect to a local SQLite database named `clinton.db`. Creating a data frame from a table of the database works fine but when I do some operations on the created object, I get the error below which says "SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)". Funny thing is that I get the result of the operation nevertheless. Any idea what I can do to solve the problem, i.e., avoid the error?

Start command for spark-shell:

```
../spark/bin/spark-shell --master local[8] --jars ../libraries/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.1.jar --classpath ../libraries/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.1.jar
```

Reading from the database:

```
val emails = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> "jdbc:sqlite:../data/clinton.sqlite", "dbtable" -> "Emails")).load()
```

Simple count (fails):

```
emails.count
```

Error:

`15/09/30 09:06:39 WARN JDBCRDD: Exception closing statement
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.internalClose(CoreStatement.java:109)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.close(JDBC3Statement.java:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JDBCRDD$$anon$$close(JDBCRDD.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$8.apply(JDBCRDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anon$1$$anonfun$8.apply(JDBCRDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anon$1.onTaskCompletion(TaskContextImpl.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:77)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
res1: Long = 7945`

Comment: Looks like an issue with the path you are giving to the .sqlite database file. Have you tried using an absolute path? Or at least not starting it with '..'? 
Perhaps the process you are running does not have perms to the parent dir.

Comment: @aguibert: I just tried an absolute path to the database but the problem still appears. I also changed the permissions of clinton.sqlite to 777 but it does not help either. The issue also appears with Spark 1.4.1 and the newly released 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error [today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33961898/2390083), and the important line is just before the exception:

> 15/11/30 12:13:02 INFO jdbc.JDBCRDD: closed connection
>
> 15/11/30 12:13:02 WARN jdbc.JDBCRDD: Exception closing statement
>   java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)
>       at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
>       at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.internalClose(CoreStatement.java:109)
>       at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.close(JDBC3Statement.java:35)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JDBCRDD$$anon$$close(JDBCRDD.scala:454)

So Spark succeeded to close the JDBC **connection**, and then it fails to close the JDBC **statement**

---

Looking at the source, `close()` is called **twice**:

Line 358 (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD, Spark 1.5.1)

```
context.addTaskCompletionListener{ context => close() }
```

Line 469

```
override def hasNext: Boolean = {
  if (!finished) {
    if (!gotNext) {
      nextValue = getNext()
      if (finished) {
        close()
      }
      gotNext = true
    }
  }
  !finished
}
```

If you look at the `close()` method (line 443)

```
def close() {
  if (closed) return
```

you can see that it checks the variable `closed`, but that value is never set to true.

If I see it correctly, this bug is still in the master. I have filed a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12048).

- Source: [JDBCRDD.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRDD.scala) (lines numbers differ slightly)

Comment: Thanks for the response and filing a bug report!

Comment: Well, I have even fixed it :-)